# Google CoLab: how to use opencv to read data from my Google drive?

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, google-colaboratory

After authorizing Google Drive, installing opencv and uploading the data in my Google Drive, I still can't read the image that I want using OpenCV

[image]
[image]

Where goes wrong? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have mounted your google drive into the drive folder your file path should be something like:

```
drive/<path_to_file_in_drive>
```